# SwiftUI get Screen size in multiplatform

Tags: ios, swiftui

Actually, i used in my `ContentView.swift` file

```
UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
```

to get width screen's size. Unfortunatelly, i can't used this with an MacOS target because it need `NSScreen`

```
NSScreen.main.bounds.size.width
```

Is there any generic `Screen` to get the screen size?

Comment: Have you tried GeometryReader? I doesn't give you the screen size but it does give you the maximum size the View can be.

Answer (score 14):

What I did, to solve this is to create a class with platform conditional.

```
class SGConvenience{
    #if os(watchOS)
    static var deviceWidth:CGFloat = WKInterfaceDevice.current().screenBounds.size.width
    #elseif os(iOS)
    static var deviceWidth:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    #elseif os(macOS)
    static var deviceWidth:CGFloat? = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.size.width // You could implement this to force a CGFloat and get the full device screen size width regardless of the window size with .frame.size.width
    #endif
}
```

Then I simply call SGConvenience.deviceWidth when needed

Answer (score 4):

i prefer the extension version:

```
// MARK UIScreen+size.swift

import UIKit

extension UIScreen
{
#if os(watchOS)
    static let screenSize = WKInterfaceDevice.current().screenBounds.size
    static let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    static let screenHeight = screenSize.height
#elseif os(iOS) || os(tvOS)
    static let screenSize = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size
    static let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    static let screenHeight = screenSize.height
#elseif os(macOS)
    static let screenSize = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.size
    static let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    static let screenHeight = screenSize.height
#endif
    static let middleOfScreen = CGPoint(x: screenWidth / 2, y: screenHeight / 2)
}
```

and use it like this:

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.screenWidth
let middlePointY = UIScreen.middleOfScreen.y
```

Comment: WatchOS doesn't have UIKit available. So this won't work, it will fail on the `import` on watch. And prefixing `screen` on everything when it's already in `UIScreen` is fairly pointless.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a cross-platform version I've created, please let me know if you spot anything amiss.

It's not yet tested on MacOS or WatchOS but compiles fine.

```
import Foundation

#if os(macOS)
import AppKit
#elseif os(iOS)
import UIKit
#elseif os(watchOS)
import WatchKit
#endif

struct Screen {
#if os(macOS)
    static var size: CGSize = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.size ?? NSScreen.main?.frame.size ?? CGSizeMake(0, 0)
#elseif os(iOS)
    static var size: CGSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
#elseif os(watchOS)
    static var size: CGSize = WKInterfaceDevice.current().screenBounds.size
#endif
    static var minX: CGFloat { 0 }
    static var minY: CGFloat { 0 }
    static var maxX: CGFloat { size.width }
    static var maxY: CGFloat { size.height }
    static var midX: CGFloat { (maxX - minX) / 2 }
    static var midY: CGFloat { (maxY - minY) / 2 }
}
```

*@Jean-Francois Fabre - my answer corresponds exactly with what's been asked here. I suggest you spend your time better elsewhere, deleting my original answer has achieved nothing but waste both our time.*